# Texture not exporting

Tags: uv, unreal-engine

I made and object in blender with checker texture but when i try to import it in unreal Engine it only imports with object. The texture is not imported

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem? What format are you exporting to?

Comment: I am exporting my checker texture to unreal Engine in fbx format but won’t go in engine.

Answer (score 1):

When you export your FBX in Blender, at the top of the Export FBX dialog, there is an option for how external data is saved ("Path Mode"). click the drop-down for that and choose "Copy". Also click the button next to it that looks like a box ("Embed Textures").

Now your texture will be exported.

NOTE: "Complicated" materials will not be preserved when you export in .fbx format. As a general rule, anything more complicated than plugging an image texture node into a material property will fail in another application. Use only `Principled BSDF` shaders and only a single `Image Texture node` for any one of its properties--those properties should be limited to PBR-workflow standby's: "Diffuse"/"Albedo", "Roughness", "Normal". You will have to rebuild the rest yourself in the game engine you import the .fbx to.

Comment: I did that but it is exporting in ue4

Comment: I don't understand, can you please be more clear?